# How to extract the track titles from this page with beautiful soup

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to learn to use beautiful soup but I'm struggling with this task.  I want to extract all the track names from this page i.e. "0001A", "3 ways to skin a cat" etc but don't understand how to do this.  I don't see this data in a div which is what the tutorial Im using is asking me to do.  Can someone please help?

Updated:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://www.residentadvisor.net/dj/greggow/tracks')
html = r.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
div = soup.find_all('div', class_= "title")
print(div)
```

Comment: Do your `div`s have any special attribute?

Comment: You don't see the `<div class='title'>`? You are supposed to check the HTML source, not what is visible in your browser.

Comment: Thanks Rad Lexus I updated the code after your feedback but now only get one track title.  How do I make the code above greedy?

Comment: I changed soup.find to soup.find_all and this looks to give me all the output I need.  It also gives me a lot of other information that I don't need.  How do I just get the track title?

Comment: @adele You can use the [get_text](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text) method on the elements to get the text inside the div. It would also contain the name of the artist though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I played around with this and without messing around with BS's methods too much I just took the easy way out and converted each div to a string and spliced it appropriately:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://www.residentadvisor.net/dj/greggow/tracks')
html = r.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
div = soup.find_all('div', class_= "title")

for each in div:

    #3 options presented themselves, either with a href or not in title

    if each.find("a"):
        #Either a link back to the track
        if "track.aspx" in each.find("a")["href"]:
            each = each.find("a").get_text()

        #or to some other weird source
        else:
            each = str(each)
            each = each[each.find(">") + 1 : each.find("<br/>") ]

    else:
        each = str(each)
        each = each[each.find(">") + 1 : each.find("<br/>") ]
    print(each)
```

This is bad form though seeing as some change to the website might break the code so I wouldn't suggest using this as a solution for future projects; but I have to get back to work.